# Yii 1.1 generateRandomString not working

Tags: yii

I am trying to generate random string of specific length using  generateRandomString of yii 1.1 but its giving CSecurityManager and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "generateRandomBytes".Can any one help?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? It clearly states `generateRandomBytes() method (available since v1.1.14)`. so if you're only running 1.1 then it won't be included

Comment: using  generateRandomString is also giving same error

Comment: What "same error"? Have you looked in the actual CSecurityManager.php file to see what methods the class has?

Comment: Actually my version is 1.1.13 so i cannot use any of this method.I have to look for some other way of generating random number.Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ircmaxell/RandomLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib). If you run composer you can install it using `composer install ircmaxell/random-lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Hii Create your own `function` inside `component` to generate `random string` and call it anywhere in your Project

`Function.php` (lets say its your a file into component folder)

```
class Function {
    public static function generateRandomString($legth = 10){

    $charaters = "01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $randomString = '';
    for($i = 0; $i<$length;$i++){
    $randomString .= $charaters[rand(0,strlen($charaters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;

    }

}
```

call it anywhere like `$randomNumber = Function::generateRandomString();`